# Laravel REST API with query parameters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I have part of an API up and running, but am stuck on a few things. I am working with Laravel's REST controllers and am loving the ability to use methods such as `Response::eloquent($query);` But, in using this:

1. How should I handle query parameters (e.g id=27&order_by=timestamp), if the resource that I am getting is joining several tables?
2. Should I get the values from the database, and then construct an array with only the certain fields that I want to display for API access? And how would this then work with query parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off I would recommend that you watch [Teach a Dog to REST](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design)[Link broken] for more information about formatting your REST routes.

As for your questions:

1. You can handle input fields through the `Input::get() and Input::all()` methods as mentioned in [laravel input & cookies docs](http://laravel.com/docs/input). You might also have to validate incoming data with laravel's Validator class.
2. Say you acquired the id and order_by fields from the input as mentioned in your example:

   `$id = Input::get('id');
   $order_criteria = Input::get('order_by');`

using Fluent Query Builder

```
DB::table('dbtable')->where('id', '=', $id)->order_by($order_criteria, 'desc')->first();
```

// Using first() since we are pretty sure that we are getting only one result out, for a different criteria where more than a result could be returned you might want to use ->get() instead.

Comment: Hey mate! I have followed Apigee's blog closely and have already learned a lot from their awesome videos. I am already doing some of what you mentioned. I guess my question really is, how do I include the query parameters in a way that is flexible for different resources? Should I extend the base controller and write some sort of function that handles query params? How would you recommend I do this?

Comment: Oh well i suppose i am not getting what you really need help with, whether how to handle the request or the formatting of the params in your URLs ? maybe you can provide some sort of examples to begin with.

Comment: Should I be constructing an array myself with only the values that I want returned in the response?

Comment: @Sneaksta you ever figure this out, or find a good resource to learn from?

Comment: @kmmathis Yep! What I ended up doing is writing a function in the base controller class that is called something like 'queryParams' and then run it in my controllers, wrapping my eloquent queries. E.g: $this->queryParams(User::where('user', '=', 'me'))->first(); This enabled me to handle the query object in the queryParams class and tag on any extra queries, according to what is in the Input::get() object.

Answer (score 3):

I released a package for this.

You can check this out https://github.com/selahattinunlu/laravel-api-query-builder

For wiki page: https://github.com/selahattinunlu/laravel-api-query-builder/wiki

This package creates query with url parameters.

Example:

/api/users?name=se*&age!=18&order_by=age,asc&limit=2&columns=name,age,city_id&includes=city

And resulting query

```
Users::with(['city'])->select(['name', 'age', 'city_id'])
                     ->where('age', '!=', 18)
                     ->where('name', 'like', 'se%')
                     ->orderBy('age', 'asc')
                     ->take(2)
```

Usage:

```
$queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder(new User, $request);

return response->json([
  'data' => $queryBuilder->build()->paginate(),
  .
  .
]);
```

That's all.

Comment: @OliverBayes-Shelton Yes I'm not maintaining it anymore. I can give push permission if anyone wants to maintain it